# Каким образом считать символы в словах циклом? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Нужно каким-то образом создать условие, которое будет проверять, сколько символов в слове, которое взято из текста, который находится в файле, сравнило его с запрошенным количеством, а затем продолжило это делать до конца StreamReader'а. Количество символов в слове должно быть меньше заданной длины.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Имя файла: text.txt");

        Console.WriteLine("Максимум букв в слове: ");

        int wordlength = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string s = "";

        string[] textMass;

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("text.txt");

        while (sr.EndOfStream != true)
        {

            s += sr.ReadLine();

        }

        textMass = s.Split(' ');
        Console.WriteLine("Выполняю анализ: ");
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= textMass.Length)
        {
            Console.Write(". ");
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Анализ завершён: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Количество слов: " + textMass.Length);

        sr.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Вот, собственно, код, он работает, но не выполняет последней нужной задачи, не фильтрует слова по длине. Прошу помощи у вас, знатоки.

Comment: Так, давайте перефразируем. вам нужно понять сколько слов в тексте больше заданной длинны? или что?

Comment: @srvr4vr Наоборот, меньше заданной длинны, извините, что не уточнил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант использую LINQ без стримов:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Имя файла: text.txt");

        Console.WriteLine("Максимум букв в слове: ");

        int wordlength = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Выполняю анализ: ");

        var wordsSmallerThan = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\tmp\\text.txt")
             .SelectMany(line => line.Split(" "))
             .Where(word => word.Length < wordlength);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Анализ завершён: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Количество слов: " + wordsSmallerThan.Count());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Поправлю ваш вариант со стрим ридером (без загрузки всего текста в память)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Имя файла: text.txt");

    Console.WriteLine("Максимум букв в слове: ");

    var wordlength = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    var result = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Выполняю анализ: ");

    //стримы и прочие IDispoisible ресурсы оборачивайте в using 
    using (var sr = new StreamReader("C:\\tmp\\text.txt"))
    {
        while (sr.EndOfStream != true)
        {
            var line = sr.ReadLine();

            var smallerWordsCount = line?.Split(" ")?.Count(word => word.Length < wordlength) ?? 0;

            result += smallerWordsCount;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Анализ завершён: ");
    Console.WriteLine("Количество слов: " + result);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Можно попросить вас объяснить, что происходит в этом блоке? Он заменяет мой код, или дополняет его?

Comment: Заменяет - это тело полностью рабочей программы

Comment: Добавил версию с стримом

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! Код работает без ошибок и полностью выполняет требуемые задачи! Очень благодарен!

Comment: Рекомендую все же второй вариант - он более щедяще будет к памяти если в тексте очень много строк

Comment: У меня не читало (" "), как символ, заменил кавычки на апострофы. Огромное спасибо вам за быстрый ответ!